# Control dependencies and order of evaluation

Tags: tensorflow

Please consider the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.device("gpu:0"):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    idx = tf.constant(0)
    # 10 iterations
    while_condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, tf.constant(10))        
    acc = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float64)
    # the body of the while adds 1 to acc in each iteration
    def body_accumulator(i):
        mainOp = tf.assign_add(acc, 1.0)
        return tf.tuple([tf.add(i, 1)], control_inputs=[mainOp])
    whileOp = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body_accumulator, [idx])

    # My idea: return acc after evaluating whileOp, whose code modifies acc
    def f(dummy):
        with tf.control_dependencies([whileOp]):
            # with return tf.identity(acc) it works
            return acc
    def g():
        return acc

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('"g: return acc .eval()" - this is the only time where I would expect 0')
    print(g().eval())
    print('f(dummy)')
    print(f(1).eval())
    print('whileOp.eval()')
    print(whileOp.eval())
    print('acc value:')
    print(acc.eval())
    print('"g: return acc .eval()"')
    print(g().eval())
```

The output is:

```
"g: return acc .eval()" - this is the only time where I would expect 0
0.0
f(dummy)
0.0
whileOp.eval()
10
acc value:
10.0
"g: return acc .eval()"
10.0
```

My question is:

why does `f(1).eval()` return 0 even if there is a control dependency on the `whileOp` that modifies the returned variable `acc`?

After reading the documentation, I was expecting `whileOp` to be evaluated before returning acc. How should I write the function `f(.)` in order to force the evaluation of `whileOp`?

In `f(.)`, if I return `tf.identity(acc)` instead of `acc`, it works as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing problems because of the weird aliasing model for tensorflow variables. This is why things work with tf.identiy but not without.

If you enable resource variables (use tf.get_variable(..., use_resource=True) to create your variables) you will get the behavior you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the "weird aliasing model for tensorflow variables" and why tf.identity works ? maybe some links ?

Comment: tf.Variables don't have a well-defined memory model. Resource variables do, and let you do things such as reading their values with control dependencies.

Comment: I have seemed to run across such a case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358306/nesting-control-dependencies-contexts-in-tensorflow - I would need some links to official docs regarding this (and an answer to my question there - NB, I tried using `use_resource=True` to no avail)

Comment: See my answer to that question

Comment: Thanks - I am also interested in some docs on that (the behavior of tf.identity for instance)

Comment: tf.identity returns a new tensor, with any control dependencies which are active on the current context, which has the same value as the old tensor