# Nesting control dependencies contexts in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Running the test below

```
from unittest import TestCase

import tensorflow as tf

class TestControl(TestCase):

  def test_control_dep(self):
    print(tf.__version__)
    a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=tf.constant(0.0))
    d_optim = tf.assign(a, a + 2)
    g_optim = tf.assign(a, a * 2)
    with tf.control_dependencies([d_optim]):
      with tf.control_dependencies([g_optim]):
        with tf.control_dependencies([g_optim]):
          op = tf.Print(a, [a])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(op)
      sess.run(op)
      sess.run(op)
```

prints (for instance):

```
1.4.0
2018-03-18 16:58:08.943349: I C:\tf_jenkins\...\logging_ops.cc:79] [0]
2018-03-18 16:58:08.943349: I C:\tf_jenkins\...\logging_ops.cc:79] [2]
2018-03-18 16:58:08.943349: I C:\tf_jenkins\...\logging_ops.cc:79] [4]
```

but I have also seen other outputs as in [2, 8, 10]. I would expect it to print [8, 40, 168] (actually I was wanting to make sure `g_optim` would execute twice which I was not sure it would). Why are not the prints deterministic and why does it not seem to always execute `g_optim`?

NB: running this on an Ubuntu GPU server on EC2 (with tensorflow 1.6) produces 0 all the time:

```
python3 -m unittest tf_test.TestControl.test_control_dep
1.6.0
2018-03-19 08:06:11.614220: ...
2018-03-19 08:06:12.282375: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9610 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
[0]
[0]
[0]
0.0
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.833s

OK
```

Maybe related:

- [Control dependencies and order of evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43916019/281545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not deterministic because you are creating the assign operations with no control dependencies, so they execute in any order.

To execute the assignments in the way you want their ops need to have control dependencies when they're created. Something like

```
a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=tf.constant(0.0))
with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(a, a + 2)]):
  with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(a, a * 2)]):
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(a, a * 2)]):
      op = tf.Print(a, [a])
```

What your code is doing is building up a set of two control dependencies and adding those dependencies to the tf.Print op.

Comment: This indeed works as expected - but _their ops need to have control dependencies when they're created_ still escapes me. I mean doesn't `with tf.control_dependencies([d_optim]):` mean that `d_optim`, that is the `tf.assign(a, a + 2)` must be executed before the `op` aka the print ? Or could this behavior mean that for instance the `assign` ops are executed anyway in random order before the print ? In other words, as the assign ops are linked to the print they should not execute unless the Print is executed (evaluated). I miss something here

Comment: The tf.control_dependencies scope only affects ops created under it, and it doesn't in itself create any ops. So when you do with tf.control_dependencies([a]): with tf.control_dependencies([b]): fn() and a and b are preexisting values this imposes no ordering constraints between a and b, just says that ops created in fn() need to happen after both a and b.

Comment: Thanks - but how then 0 is printed (consistently in tf 1.6 on ubuntu) ? Even if the `g_optim`, `d_optim` are executed in random order shouldn't `d_optim = tf.assign(a, a + 2)` be executed before the print so `a` should be at least 2?

Comment: Or is it that the values of the `d_optim` are never seen (or sometimes seen) by the `g_optim = tf.assign(a, a * 2)` that may perform multiplication on "stale" 0 value ? That gets real messy

Comment: a * 2 might read the original value of a, 0, and then overwrite the addition, if everything is running concurrently

Comment: Thanks - I am accepting although it would be great to have some links to official docs discussing this.

Comment: I haven't seen this documented actually :) Links to docs would be welcome

Comment: tf.identity and tf.control_dependencies have documentation which would be the relevant one here